# Convert a string to decimal in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, format, decimal

What will be the easiest way to convert a string to decimal?

Input:

```
a = 40000.00-
```

Output will be

```
40,000.00-
```

I tried to use this code:

```
Dim a as string

a = "4000.00-"

a = Format$(a, "#,###.##")
console.writeline (a)
```

Comment: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 16):

Use `Decimal.Parse` to convert to decimal number, and then use `.ToString("format here")` to convert back to a string.

```
Dim aAsDecimal as Decimal = Decimal.Parse(a).ToString("format here")
```

Last resort approach (not recommended):

```
string s = (aAsDecimal <0) ? Math.Abs(aAsDecimal).ToString("##,###0.00") + "-" : aAsDecimal .ToString("##,###0.00");
```

You will have to translate to Visual Basic.

Comment: I try this but the result i want is negative should be at the end.
   
               Dim a as string

               a = "4000.00-"
               a = Decimal.Parse(a).ToString("##,###.00")
               console.writeline (a)

               ' result 4,000.00

Comment: Else there is the unrecommended approach: (a<0) ? Math.Abs(a).ToString("##,###0.00") + "-" : a.ToString("##,###0.00");

Comment: still no luck. I'll try it in a different way.  I'll post it here once I got it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: My last resort approach will def work. Though not entirely elegant.

Comment: When I convert to VB I got an error  Dim s As String = If((a < 0), Math.Abs(a).ToString("##,###0.00") & "-", a.ToString("##,###0.00"))

Comment: Dim aAsDecimal as Decimal = Decimal.Parse(a) then use aAsDecimal in the statement I gave you.

Comment: this is the website I used to convert your code http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: My original used a which is defined as a string. Which is why I introduced aAsADecimal. You probably getting a typecast exception or something.

Answer (score 7):

For VB.NET:

```
CDec(Val(string_value))
```

For example,

```
CDec(Val(a))
```

The result will be `40000D` or if the value for a = "400.02" then it will be `400.02D`.

Answer (score 6):

Use Decimal.TryParse

```
Dim a as string
Dim b as Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(a, b) Then
   a = b.ToString("##,###.00")
Else
   a = "can not parse"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine for me, but I don't know whether it is correct or not.

```
double a = 40000.00;
a = double.Parse(a.ToString("##,###.00"));
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString("##,###.00"));
```

Comment: middle line is unnecessary.  You're converting a double to a string and then parsing it again back to double. Now, if you're trying to truncate extra decimal places (ie: 40000.0001 to 40000.00), that will work, but Math.Round(a, 2) will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim convert As Func(Of String, Decimal) = _
    Function(x As String) Decimal.Parse(x) ' This is a lambda expression.
    Dim a = convert("-16325.62")
    Dim spec As String = "N"
    Console.WriteLine("{1}", spec, a.ToString(spec))
    'Console.ReadLine() ' Uncomment to see value in Console output.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim D@ = CDec(TextBox1.Text) '//convert string to decimal with short
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but it is quite long:

```
 Dim a as string 
 Dim b as decimal

 a = "4000.00-" 
 b = a

 If b >= 0 then
     console.writeline (b.ToString("##,###.00"))
 Else
     b = Math.Abs(b)
     console.writeline (b.ToString("##,###.00") & "-")
 End if
```